# Adding database connection to ArcSDE database?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am unable to connect to the SDE database we have in house on my new CPU and not quite sure what's going on. I don't have much experience with SDE but seems like the connection should be quite simple. I can connect to the SDE database on another computer using a username and password as it was already set up. But with this new computer, no dice. Not sure if there is something else that needs to be installed on my new machine to make the first connection or if there is something else I am missing. IT is trying to help but they are stumped as well. Here are stats for both CPU:

New CPU with no SDE connection:
Windows 10
64-bit
32 GB RAM
Intel Core i7-6700 CPU
Running ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2

Old CPU with successful connection:
Windows 8
64-bit
8 GB RAM
Intel Xeon CPU E5-1620 v2
Running ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2

Comment: sounds like an oracle (or other db) client is not set up on the new pc see http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/connect-oracle.htm

Comment: @Mapperz you nailed it - thank you so much. We installed SQL server native client on the new CPU and it worked like charm.

Comment: Be sure to give appropriate user roles for each user.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). It is important to be sure to always include exact database details in each GIS database question.  Note that there is no such thing as an "SDE database" -- Esri is a GIS software firm, not an RDBMS company. "SDE" no longer exists; the current term of art is "enterprise geodatabase".

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the advice. I have taken the tour and will do my best to use appropriate terms in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in the comments:

You need to install an Oracle or other database client on the new machine and ensure that you set up appropriate user roles.

Please see this article for more information about connecting to Oracle databases:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/connect-oracle.htm

Comment: The OP's RDBMS is SQL Server. If you're going to answer from someone else's comment, please make sure the answer corresponds to the information in **all** the comments.

Comment: @Vince Delete my answer if you don't like it.  You're a mod after all.  I'm just trying to help.

Comment: I am **not** a moderator. I *am* suggesting that answers should answer the question, especially if the actual question has been resolved by the first comment.

Comment: LOL.  No you're not.  You have mod tools tho.  Thanks for answering.  Your answer is better.  I was just trying to get rid of unanswered questions where the question has been answered in comments.  That way they don't keep popping up in the list when they've been answered already.

Comment: There are so many unanswered questions here that it hardly seems worth the effort to answer incomplete ones.

Comment: Maybe that's why there are so many unanswered questions.  The answer wasn't incomplete.  They didn't have a database client installed.  Installing a database client fixes the problem.  It doesn't have to be oracle as I specified "Oracle or OTHER database client".  Just because you provided a more detailed answer doesn't mean mine didn't answer the question that was asked (it was accepted after all).

Comment: Not your answer, the ***question*** was incomplete (it still is).

Comment: Ok.  I got you now.  Good point.  It is a bit of an uphill battle and difficult when people don't use standard terminology or follow the rules of the site.  We can only hope that the info helps someone somewhere.  Your answer will definitely help someone.

Answer (score 3):

While the ArcSDE component organizes database access to ArcGIS clients, it is the RDBMS client libraries which provide connectivity.  Esri makes some database vendors' installers available, but PostgreSQL is the only database which has client libraries installed within ArcGIS clients by default.

Therefore, for all connectivity questions, the following questions must be resolved:

1. Is the necessary RDBMS client installed?
2. Does the RDBMS client have IP connectivity to the server?
3. Is the database configured in a form compatible with ArcGIS access?

The ArcGIS documentation has dozens of pages for each of the five major RDBMS it supports, but a good generic starting point would be the [Manage Data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/main/what-is-geodata.htm) page, with Databases, Geodatabases, and Administering geodatabases main topics along the left side.  The [Database clients](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/database-clients.htm) page provides details on what clients are supported.

Each RDBMS has its own tools for connectivity, and even when the client libraries are installed, server firewall or access permissions may need to be granted before a successful connection can be made.  The [Troubleshoot connections to a database](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/troubleshoot-connections.htm) page details possible issues.

Due to case sensitivity in some databases, there may be database, schema, table, or column properties which might prevent ArcGIS connectivity.  In general, it is unwise to use mixed-case in names of database objects, because ArcGIS clients are unlikely to be able to see them.  There are also a number of datatypes available in databases which cannot be mapped to common types by the Direct Connect (ArcSDE) communication protocol, and even some types (64-bit integers) which are not accessible by ArcGIS Desktop or Server clients.  The [DBMS data types supported in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/dbms-data-types-supported.htm) page provides references to supported types.

In your particular case, with Microsoft SQL Server, the appropriate Native Client libraries need to be installed (which one depends on the exact release of SQL Server).  The [Microsoft SQL Server database requirements](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm) page provides details on the supported database versions and which client may be necessary.